# How to get average with rows in pig

Tags: python, apache-pig

Through the following processing

```
REGISTER 's3://jmh-dtg-2016/jeon_dtg/test.py' USING jython as test;
raw01  = LOAD 's3://jmh-dtg-2016/jeon_dtg/test_pig.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER');
raw02 = FOREACH raw01 GENERATE (chararray)$2 as date, (chararray)$3 as code, (chararray)$4 as car_num, (chararray)$5 as pre_time, (FLOAT)$8 as vel, (chararray)$18 as link_id;
raw03 = GROUP raw02 BY (link_id, car_num);
raw04 = FOREACH raw03 GENERATE group, test.my_fun(raw02.vel) AS val;
dump raw04;
```

Got these results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUQ9d.png)

i wanna get average of each rows.
In conclusion, I want results like this :

```
{(39.0),(45.0)}) -> 42 
{(1.0)}) -> 1
```

This is the python function I used.

```
@outputSchema('num01:float')
def my_fun(data01):
    a = data01
    b = sorted(a)
    c = int((len(b)/100.0) * 10.0)
    d = int((len(b)/100.0) * 90.0)
    e = b[c:d]
    return e
```

and it is impossible

```
 @outputSchema('num01:float')
    def my_fun(data01):
        a = data01
        b = sorted(a)
        c = int((len(b)/100.0) * 10.0)
        d = int((len(b)/100.0) * 90.0)
        e = b[c:d]
        return sum(e)
```

help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to get the average from a bag of values? Correct me if I'm wrong. The PIG operator AVG should do this and will be more performant than a Python UDF.

```
raw04 = FOREACH raw03 GENERATE group, AVG(raw02.vel) AS val;
```